# Use Panels + CTools Page Manager Node Template with Views Row Style Node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-panels

I have used Panels + CTools Page Manager to configure the 'Node template' (node_view) for a particular content type. When viewing these nodes at /node/% the Page Manager's node template renders the nodes just fine.

However, when trying to display a 'Row style: Node' version of these nodes with a View, the nodes are rendered using my default node.tpl.php file.

How do you setup Views 'Row style: Node' to utilize the Panels + CTools Page Manager Node Template?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that might work.  Both require Drupal experience or research.

1. IF you add CSS styling to the view or panel, you can then create custom CSS for your theme.
2. You can try defining a Theme listed in Views in the Advanced column, under others.  Some of the template files exist, and others are only suggestions (They have two underscores between words instead of one). If you put a copy of a selected tpl.php file in your theme folder it will override the main one and you can make changes there.